# Problemas ao tentar listar csv

Tags: php, cmd

Ola,

Estou tentando ler os arquivos do tipo csv de uma pasta via script.

via browser ele me apresenta os valores corretos do array, porem via CLI me apresenta um array vazio.
Segue o codigo

```
$files = glob('*.csv');
var_dump($files);
```

Output via browser:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(22) "Perdas\Score_Gauss.csv" [1]=> string(16) "Perdas\teste.csv" }
```

Output via CLI:

```
array(0){}
```

Alguma ideia do porque isso pode estar ocorrendo?

Comment: O código está correto, eu faria de outra maneira mas ficaria muito grande o código. O servidor que você está rodando é na sua máquina? Talvez falte parte do caminho de diretorio (PATH), um nível acima provavelmente não existe arquivos CSV e por isso lista 0 arrays.

Comment: Cara, nao acredito. Sua pergunta me fez pensar no porque em um funciona e no outro nao. Acontece que no browser quem gerencia o caminho é meu IIS, ou seja, eu utilizo o caminho relativo, enquanto no CLI eu preciso usar o caminho completo ! Como faço pra marcar sua resposta como correta?

Comment: Desculpa, você só pode avaliar comentários (diferentes de respostas) quando tiver `reputação` necessária, mesmo assim vou por como resposta.

Comment: Eu acho incrivel a quantidade de pessoas que corrigem o texto, mas nao dão uma ideia de como solucionar o problema. Um cara teve a moral de corrigir retirando o "Olá", como se isso fosse fator decisivo para o bom entendimento do problema.

Comment: Relaxa. Eu também sou novo aqui, mas entendi que o nível deles é pra beneficiar a comunidade. Tornando os tópicos mais dentro do padrão possível. Eles revisam tópicos aleatoriamente o que lhes garante pontos também. Agora mudando de assunto. Espero que a minha resposta tenha solucionado seu problema. Se sim por gentileza marque ela como a resposta correta no sinal de **visto**. Abraço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código está correto, eu faria de outra maneira mas ficaria muito grande o código. O servidor que você está rodando é na sua máquina? Talvez falte parte do caminho de diretorio (PATH), um nível acima provavelmente não existe arquivos CSV e por isso lista 0 arrays.

Por exemplo, no servidor o caminho do arquivo pode variar:

```
/htdocs/www/
```

Na sua máquina pode ser:

```
C:\xampp\www
```